# How do I disable dictionary lookup in web browser input field?

Tags: html, browser

When the user enters a date, it is underlined in red (because it's not in a dictionary somewhere).  This is certainly an issue in FF, probably most browsers.  Is there a way to flag an input field as "don't expect English words here?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `spellcheck` attribute.  Tested in Firefox 3.0:

```
<html><body>
<textarea>Teh speling is checkd.</textarea>
<textarea spellcheck='false'>Teh speling is not checkd.</textarea>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Score another one for Stack Overflow!